# What is the right phrase describing a meeting in school with parents?

Tags: word-choice

As a teacher, which of the following should I say?

> - We have a teacher–parent meeting on Monday 9th.
> - We have a teacher–parents meeting on Monday 9th.
> - We have a parent–teacher conference on Monday 9th.

Comment: Those are all grammatical sentences. What are you having trouble making your mind up about?

Comment: Are all of the above sentences acceptable then?

Comment: Indeed they are.

Comment: All the three are correct. But the **third** one sounds very common, correct, and not odd.

Comment: _Parent-Teacher Conference_ (capitals optional) is the usual phrase in the United States.

Comment: To my U.S. ear, "Monday 9th" sounds odd, although clear (if the month is obvious). "Monday, the 9th" would be more typical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with others that **parent-teacher** is much more commonly used than the other way around.  The word "conference" is very common, but also commonly used is "*parent-teacher **interview***".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the second sentence; why would one word be singular and the other plural? That looks odd to me. And probably out of respect to the parents, I think 'parent' usually come first. Remember the song  is Harper Valley PTA (parent-teacher association), not TPA.

I've just Googled 'teacher parents meeting', and the first page showed overwhelmingly 'parent-teacher' meeting.

Comment: I checked Google Books, where *"parent-teacher meeting"* gets 11,400 hits, against only 614 for *"teacher-parent meeting"*. The figures aren't quite so overwhelmingly biased for *"conference"*, but they're similar. +1 for Harper Valley PTA, but you are right anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the first sentence ("We have a teacher-parent meeting on Monday 9th"), but the other two are equally valid. The third sentence uses *conference*, for which one of the definitions is "a formal meeting for discussion."